# how to get a result data from range date in DatatableRepository Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, datatable, spring-data-jpa

The table already had date column, and i wish to get result not just by one date, but range of 2 dates using DatatableRepository on SpringJPA

this is my current controller on using datatable:

```
    @PostMapping("/datatable")
    public DataTablesOutput<MyData> getMyDatatable(@Valid @RequestBody DataTablesInput input) {
        return myDataRepository.findAll(input);
    }
```

this is how i call the data on my insomnia:

```
{
    "draw":1,
    "columns":[
        {
            "data":"date",
            "name":"date",
            "searchable":true,
            "orderable":true,
            "search":
                {
                    "value":"2023-03-07",
                    "regex":false
                }
        }
    ]
    ,"order":[
        {
            "column":0,
            "dir":"asc"
        }
    ],
    "start":0,
    "length":100,
    "search":{
        "value":"","regex":false
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. PostMapping about modification data, in this case usefull GetMapping
 2. findAll returns all data usually. how will DataTablesInput affect the result? should there be some sort of filtering?

Comment: found this, but don't know how to call it in the insomnia
https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables#range-of-dates

Comment: this is the specification. this mechanism is needed to obtain data on dynamically changing conditions (as an example, a filter). if you need to get all the data strictly between two dates, you can add to Repository this method List<Entity> findByColumnDateBetween(LocalDateTime to, LocalDateTime from);

Answer (score 0):

In your repository add a method:

```java
interface DatatableRepository extends CrudRepository {
    List<MyData>findByDateColumnBetween(Instant from, Instant to);
}
```

This assumes that the property you want to filter by is called `dateColumn`.

Use the method to obtain data filter by the date range.
You may use different date type depending on your requirements.

Comment: i did try this, and it works, but doesn't give the same response as datatable output

Comment: what do you mean by "datatable output"?